# Spherical Integral from a dot product in d dimensions

Tags: integration, improper-integrals, vector-analysis, quantum-field-theory

I was doing some integrals in arbitrary dimensions, and I know the answer I am supposed to get, but I cant seem to get there.

The integral is

$$\int d^D k e^{i\vec{k} \cdot \vec{r}} \frac{1}{k^2+m^2}$$

I know that  I should tranform the dot product as $kr \cos( \theta)= kru$, but when I do this, I get 
$$ \int d k \hspace{0.25 cm }k^{D-1} \int du \hspace{0.25cm} e^{i k r u} \frac{1}{k^2 +m^2}= \frac{1}{i r} \int dk \hspace{0.25 cm} k^{D-2} \frac{\sin(kr)}{k^2 +m^2}$$
 I always just end up with a 1/r dependence when doing the contour integration in the upper half plane instead of the $1/r^{D-1}$ that would be correct.

Where am I making the mistake?

Comment: I know I should get $$\frac{1}{S_{d-2} r^{d-2}}$$ as the end result, which gives the inverse square law for D=3

Comment: $r^{2 - D}$ cannot be correct. Take $D = 3$: the FT of $1/r$ is $C/k^2$, not $C/(k^2 + m^2)$. Further, this makes sense as the FT of distributions, not of ordinary functions. The triple integral of $e^{i \mathbf r \cdot \mathbf k}/(k^2 + m^2)$ is not absolutely convergent, so the iterated integrals may diverge or converge to different values when taken in different orders. In the distributional sense,
$$((k^2 + m^2)^{-1}, e^{i \mathbf r \cdot \mathbf k}) =
(2 \pi)^{D/2} \left( \frac m r \right)^{D/2 - 1} K_{D/2 - 1}(m r)$$
for $m > 0$, giving $C r^{2 - D}$ in the limit for $m \to 0^+$.

Comment: That would be the correct answer, the limit should be for $m \rightarrow 0^+$ as this is the expression for a meson mediated force where the meson is given an arbitrarily small mass. I had forgotten this limit. Thank you very much!